# How to pick elements covering particular statements in R

Tags: r

I have a text file in which there are lots of different email addresses. I want to keep the ones ending with `@atauni.edu.tr`. How can I do that in R?

Comment: You want to search for regular expressions (tag [tag:regex] on stackoverflow). What effort have you made so far to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried using `if`, but don't know which function keeps the email addresses ending with `@atauni.edu.tr`

Comment: Do your search. Hint: `?grepl`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik, thanks.  `data[grepl("@atauni.edu.tr", data)]` is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code as you suggested, in example:

```
data[grepl("@atauni.edu.tr", data)]
```